# What search engine does Craft CMS come with?

Tags: search

New to Craft CMS. Our corporate website has been built using Craft. When using the site search, it is not finding all pages within the site. Wondering what the search engine technology is and how to re-index or broaden. Also, not crazy about the search results (SERP) display. What customizations are available?

Answer (score 3):

The Craft CMS documentation has [some technical information](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) about how searching works with the various Craft ElementTypes.

There is also documentation on [setting up a search form](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/search-form).

If you're looking for a more complete and full-featured search solution, [SquareBit's Search Plus](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus) is an excellent option.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. So it appears from the documentation that the Craft search form only permits searching content hosted in Craft.  We have other subdomain (content hosted on other platforms) that I would like to have indexed as well. Is that possible within CRAFT? Or is it recommended that we procure another search technology (google or other)

Comment: That's not possible using Craft's native search. It _may_ be possible using some trickery with SearchPlus, as it uses Algolia behind the scenes, but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built in search for the front end - you have to make the search system yourself, so you have full control over the display of results because you build the whole thing.

By the sound of it you're expecting some sort of search module you can play with in the CMS - that's not likely to be how your site was built. This means that it depends on how your developer has implemented the search template your website is using. You'll need to either learn the template language and play yourself, or else go to a Craft developer who can help you.